# Map String Dynamic access var in flutter

Tags: android, hashmap, flutter

I have the next json code:

```
{"Images":{"1":{"file":"adv721899378.jpg","transTime":"15","type":"image"},"2":{"file":"adv725496177.jpg","transTime":"8","type":"image"}}}
```

I want to get to each individual file name.

I tried the following:

```
static Map<String, dynamic> jsonCode = json.decode(jsonFromHost);
Map<String, dynamic> mediaUrls = jsonCode["Images"];

for(var i=0; i<mediaUrls.length;i++) {
  print("length: " + mediaUrls.length.toString() + " | i: " + i.toString());
  Map<String, dynamic> images = mediaUrls[i];
  print('Howdy, ${mediaUrls[i]["file"]}!');
}
```

with no success - because the proper indication is mediaUrls["1"]["file"] and not [1]["files"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using string interpolation, like this way:

```
 print('Howdy, ${mediaUrls[(i+1).toString()]["file"]}!');
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Howdy, ${mediaUrls[(i+1).toString()]["file"]}!');
```

this is was the correct way.
Thank you!